# Reformatting a dataframe to access it for sort after concatenating two series

Tags: python, pandas

I've joined or concatenated two series into a dataframe. However one of the issues I'm not facing is that I have no column headings on the actual data that would help me do a sort

```
hist_a = pd.crosstab(category_a, category, normalize=True)
hist_b = pd.crosstab(category_b, category, normalize=True)
counts_a = pd.Series(np.diag(hist_a), index=[hist_a.index])
counts_b = pd.Series(np.diag(hist_b), index=[hist_b.index])   
df_plots = pd.concat([counts_a, counts_b], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

The data looks like the following:

```
                      0             1
category                        
0017817703277  0.000516  5.384341e-04
0017817703284  0.000516  5.384341e-04
0017817731348  0.000216  2.856169e-04
0017817731355  0.000216  2.856169e-04
```

and I'd like to do a sort, but there are no proper column headings

```
df_plots = df_plots.sort_values(by=['0?'])
```

But the dataframe seems to be in two parts. How could I better structure the dataframe to have 'proper' columns such as `'0'` or `'plot a'` rather than being indexable by an integer, which seems to be hard to work with.

```
category       plot a    plot b           
0017817703277  0.000516  5.384341e-04
0017817703284  0.000516  5.384341e-04
0017817731348  0.000216  2.856169e-04
0017817731355  0.000216  2.856169e-04
```

Comment: You may want to rename column header?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh. No, I believe it is the structure that needs to be changed.

Comment: Would changing the column names work? You can try `df.columns = [‘plot a’, ‘plot b’]`.

Comment: Your first output is indexed by `category`, you can use `df.reset_index()` to reset the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename the columns of the dataframe, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,23]})
df = df.rename(columns={0:'new name'})
```

If you have a lot of columns you rename all of them at once like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,23]})
rename_dict = {key: f'Col {key}' for key in df.keys() }
df = df.rename(columns=rename_dict)
```

You can also define the series with the name, so you avoid changing the name afterwards:

```
counts_a = pd.Series(np.diag(hist_a), index=[hist_a.index], name = 'counts_a')
counts_b = pd.Series(np.diag(hist_b), index=[hist_b.index], name = 'counts_b')
```